# How to generate fixed length hash based on current date and time in Php?

Tags: php, hash

I want to generate a fixed-length (say 10 characters) hash based on current date & time. This hash will be append to names of the uploaded files from my users. How can I do that in Php?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at https://www.sitepoint.com/password-hashing-in-php/.

Comment: Just use `time()` -- it's fixed at 10 characters until 2286. :)

Comment: You could `hash($algorithm, $data)` but you can't choose the length

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way I can think of:

```
$hash = md5(time());
```